Creating a Toplevel window using tkinterDnD2
I'm using tkinterDnD2 for my python GUI. I'm quite familiar with tkinter and, if I want to create a Toplevel window with another windoe, root as a parent, then I'd use the code
import tkinter as tk

toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)

However, if I try using tkinterDnD2 for the same task
from tkinterdnd2 import *

toplevel = TkinterDnD.Toplevel(root)

I get the error
    toplevel = TkinterDnD.Toplevel(root)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'tkinterdnd2.TkinterDnD' has no attribute 'Toplevel'

The documentation doesn't help that much on this regard and I was hoping that perhaps someone here knew how to create a toplevel window using tkinterDnD2 (or if it was possible). I'm trying to create a window (different from my main window), that has drag and drop capabilities.

There simply isn't a DnD-capable version of Toplevel in that module.  I'm not sure whether that's an oversight, or if it simply isn't needed - the module version of Tk is supposed to automatically enable DnD in all descendant widgets, and you're making your Toplevel a child of root, so this may just work if you use the plain Tkinter Toplevel.  If it doesn't work, you could try copying the definition of class Tk from the bottom of TkinterDnD.py (it's only 6 lines long )into your script, and changing all three occurrences of Tk to Toplevel.

The logic of the answer to this question applies to Toplevel as well.

@jasonharper 's comment solves it: if the main window is a tkinterdnd, then any tk.Toplevel window, with said main window as parent, will also have DnD capabilities.
